# Sort array of subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have this collection of Stores in my database, a store document has the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb221faf4f7171bc008d76a"),
    "name" : "Kwkik-E Market",
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bb58e6285f54d1b38e3ff73"),
            "title" : "KKCK",
            "typeOfItem" : "alcohol",
            "sellingPrice" : 5.75,
        }, 
        {
            "verified" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bb79d4ac24fdd2298ffd530"),
            "title" : "Vino Tindo D.O. Canarias",
            "sellingPrice" : 23,
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bbbd28dd186de13044e6137"),
            "title" : "Test",
            "typeOfItem" : "alcohol",
            "sellingPrice" : 17.25,
        },
}
```

How could I return that same document but with the array of products sorted by their sellingPrice? Is it better to sort the subdocument when pushing a new subdocument to the array?

Comment: You just need to return it sorted? If I were you I'd do it application side. If you read a lot more often than you write, I'd sort it on insertion so you don't have to sort it on every read (so what you suggested in the question). If you already have documents that need to be sorted you could use the $sort operator as described here to migrate them: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/

Comment: I indeed do way more reading than writing, so Im guessing the best way would be to call .update, then push the new document and sort, but, would this sort sort out all the document in the array or just the pushed documents?

Comment: You could call update once with $sort (see in the documentation where it talks about passing `[]` to `$each` so it only sorts). Then every time you update, use `$position` to put the new item in the right slot like `db.stores.update({ $push: { products: { $each: [myNewProduct], $position: x } } })` where `x` is the correct sorted position for the new product

Comment: Also though, if you're never going to have a ton of products, you could just sort it in your application code after you get the document from the DB but before you return it to the end user--don't optimize unless it's necessary.

Comment: Why do you keep adding spelling errors that I've fixed for you?

Comment: You're 2 years late for that my man

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you want to do

```js
db.yourcollectionhere.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$products'
    },
    {
        $sort: {
           products: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: '$_id',
                name: '$name'
            },
            products: {$push: '$products'}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$_id._id',
            name: '$_id.name',
            products: '$products'
        }
    }
])
```

I hope this helps!